# Incorrectly overriding a package

Tags: java, android, overriding

I am getting this error.

> 03-22 11:41:20.439 20933-20933/com.androidcss.jsonexample E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
>   03-22 11:41:20.760 20933-20933/com.androidcss.jsonexample W/art: Before Android 4.1, method int android.support.v7.widget.ListViewCompat.lookForSelectablePosition(int, boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.androidcss.jsonexample;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // CONNECTION_TIMEOUT and READ_TIMEOUT are in milliseconds
    public static final int CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 10000;
    public static final int READ_TIMEOUT = 15000;
    private RecyclerView mRVFishPrice;
    private AdapterFish mAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //Make call to AsyncTask
        new AsyncLogin().execute();


    }

    private class AsyncLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        ProgressDialog pdLoading = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        HttpURLConnection conn;
        URL url = null;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            //this method will be running on UI thread
            pdLoading.setMessage("\tLoading...");
            pdLoading.setCancelable(false);
            pdLoading.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {

                // Enter URL address where your json file resides
                // Even you can make call to php file which returns json data
                url = new URL("https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=the-next-web&sortBy=latest&apiKey=bdba5de1b490495796a1595f77ed3f37");

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                return e.toString();
            }
            try {

                // Setup HttpURLConnection class to send and receive data from php and mysql
                conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setReadTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT);
                conn.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
                conn.setRequestMethod("GET");

                // setDoOutput to true as we recieve data from json file
                conn.setDoOutput(true);

            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
                return e1.toString();
            }

            try {

                int response_code = conn.getResponseCode();

                // Check if successful connection made
                if (response_code == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                    // Read data sent from server
                    InputStream input = conn.getInputStream();
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
                    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
                    String line;

                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        result.append(line);
                    }

                    // Pass data to onPostExecute method
                    return (result.toString());

                } else {

                    return ("unsuccessful");
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return e.toString();
            } finally {
                conn.disconnect();
            }


        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            //this method will be running on UI thread

            pdLoading.dismiss();
            List<Item> data=new ArrayList<>();

            pdLoading.dismiss();
            try {

                JSONObject object= new JSONObject(result);
                JSONArray array = object.getJSONArray("articles");

                // Extract data from json and store into ArrayList as class objects
                for(int i=0;i<array.length();i++){
                    JSONObject json_data = array.getJSONObject(i);
                    Item item= new Item();
                    item.name= json_data.getString("title");

                    data.add(item);
                }

                // Setup and Handover data to recyclerview
                mRVFishPrice = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.fishPriceList);
                mAdapter = new AdapterFish(MainActivity.this, data);
                mRVFishPrice.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                mRVFishPrice.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this));

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }

    }
}
```

**AdapterFish.java**

```
package com.androidcss.jsonexample;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class AdapterFish extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    List<Item> data= Collections.emptyList();
    Item current;
    int currentPos=0;

    // create constructor to innitilize context and data sent from MainActivity
    public AdapterFish(Context context, List<Item> data){
        this.context=context;
        inflater= LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.data=data;
    }

    // Inflate the layout when viewholder created
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.card, parent,false);
        MyHolder holder=new MyHolder(view);
        return holder;
    }

    // Bind data
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        // Get current position of item in recyclerview to bind data and assign values from list
        MyHolder myHolder= (MyHolder) holder;
        Item current=data.get(position);

        myHolder.name.setText(current.getName());

        // load image into imageview using glide
        /*Glide.with(context).load("http://192.168.1.7/test/images/" + current.fishImage)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_img_error)
                .error(R.drawable.ic_img_error)
                .into(myHolder.ivFish);*/

    }

    // return total item from List
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data.size();
    }


    class MyHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        TextView name;


        // create constructor to get widget reference
        public MyHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            name = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);


        }

    }

}
```

**Item.java**

```
package com.androidcss.jsonexample;

public class Item {

    String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Comment: call `LayoutManager` before `setAdapter` to `recyclerview` steps should be like Instantiate `recyclerview` > then set `LayoutManager` to it > then `setAdapter`

Comment: I just tried it. Did not work.

Comment: Please use Volley to make API calls instead of implementing Custom Background Task and messing up the Actual Code. Volley is Cleaner and efficient. And for your asked problem, I have provided the answer already.

Comment: Yes, you were right. I could not understand properly as I am a beginner

Answer (score 4):

You need to `setLayoutManager` before `setAdapter`.

Answer (score 1):

You are initializing the `RecyclerView` in `AsyncTask`, that means your `RecyclerView` is not ready when the view is created.

Make the following changes.

```
//make list as global variable
private List<Item> data;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //view should be initialized in UI thread
    data=new ArrayList<>();
    mRVFishPrice = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.fishPriceList);
    mAdapter = new AdapterFish(MainActivity.this, data);
    mRVFishPrice.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this));
    mRVFishPrice.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    //Make call to AsyncTask
    new AsyncLogin().execute();
}
```

**Then in your `onPostExecute`**

replace -

```
mRVFishPrice = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.fishPriceList);
mAdapter = new AdapterFish(MainActivity.this, data);
mRVFishPrice.setAdapter(mAdapter);
mRVFishPrice.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this));
```

with

```
mAdapter.notifyDatasetChanged();
```

**and also, make sure you remove the `List<Item> data` from postexecute and make it global**

> And please use Volley to make API calls instead of implementing Custom
>   Background Task. Volley Handles the API calls asynchronously without
>   messing up your Actual Code.

Comment: That helped. And I will use volley in future projects. I am facing another problem. I did exactly what you said, and I am getting this error as a toast when I run the application  :  "org.json.JSONException: Value unsuccessful of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject". And in the monitor I get this : "03-24 22:45:12.696 6213-6213/com.androidcss.jsonexample W/art: Before Android 4.1, method int android.support.v7.widget.ListViewCompat.lookForSelectablePosition(int, boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView"

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue. The problem was in Layout. You should first verify that if your Views and Layouts are in correct order.